# Android to update geofence regularly

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location

I am reading through documentation from here.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing

It can update me location for my geofence when I run that service. Problem is I need to monitor continuously. So, I am thinking to do timer in my service and check my geofence regularly. But, I think it will definitely drain battery.

I don't want to monitor location and instead, I need android OS to update me whether user goes inside my geofence just like iOS. Is there any way to implement that ?

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
    // ...
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
            // multiple geofences.
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                    this,
                    geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences
            );

            // Send notification and log the transition details.
            sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
                    geofenceTransition));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to monitor geofence continuously. Create geofence and sit back, Geofence will notify you when you are in the geofence area.

Comment: Where shall I create geofence? In main activity or service? It is because user can kill app.

Comment: I am not sure about your app workflow. But maybe you can create geofence when your app starts. Once you create the geofence, even if the user kills the app, You will be notified.

Comment: ah okay. let me try. there is one thing I don't understand. Do I need to start GeofenceTransitionsIntentService ? Or mGeofencingClient will invoke GeofenceTransitionsIntentService automatically?

Comment: You don't need to start GeofenceTransitionsIntentService. You need to specify this service while creating Geofence. Geofence will invoke the service for you.